# In Amazon Redshift is it possible to have a condition on two columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following table, shown below. I want to extract the rows that have the smallest ***Row_Flag*** for their ***Group***, WHERE the ***Record_Flag*** is equal to 0. If the ***Record_Flag*** is not equal to 0, the logic should extract the next smallest ***Row_Flag*** where the ***Record_Flag*** is equal to 0. These rows are highlighted in yellow. I'm not sure if it's possible to perform this kind of "double conditional" logic in Redshift's SQL Editor. Is it possible to compute this kind of logic in Redshift? If so, how would I go about doing so?

[image: Picture of Table]

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag.  Postgres really has nothing to do with RedShift these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  I interpret your question as your wanting the smallest `row_flag` when the `record_flag = 0`.  And that `record_flag` only takes on the values `0` and `1`.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group
                                order by record_flag, row_flag
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```